# onChildAdded is calling twice?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Though this question is asked before, it was not answered correctly. The following code calls createNewCommentNotification(commenterUid, postsModel); method twice . What is the solution.

[image]

```
Query commentQuery = databaseReference.child("Notifications/NewComment").child(mUser.getUid());

commentQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            final String commenterUid = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                final PostsModel postsModel = ds.getValue(PostsModel.class);
                createNewCommentNotification(commenterUid, postsModel);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) { }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) { }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

Below is the JSON data at Notifications node

```
    {
  "NewComment" : {
    "q55o2IU76OS0ewhEW6thVALevwZ2" : {
      "OmF2nnyrgRWyQ5EtyKN5hQjPU723" : {
        "8445392926859" : {
          "customId" : "8451940719828",
          "dist" : "Jorhat",
          "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-first-95f01.appspot.com/o/Photos%2Fq55o2IU76OS0ewhEW6thVALevwZ2%2F8445392926859.jpg?alt=media&token=d509d929-e72f-4639-b96f-0e2923f7a2c7",
          "money" : 0,
          "newPostKey" : "8445392912509",
          "post" : "",
          "postId" : "8445392926859",
          "thumbImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-first-95f01.appspot.com/o/PostsThumb%2Fq55o2IU76OS0ewhEW6thVALevwZ2%2F8445392926859.jpg?alt=media&token=37e136ea-5cb6-4442-a049-25fc5be1af1b",
          "time" : 1554607086944,
          "userId" : "q55o2IU76OS0ewhEW6thVALevwZ2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you log `ds.getKey()` inside the loop, what does it show for both cases?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Logging ds.getKey() shows the Post key is 8445392926859 but twice

Comment: Hmmm... and are there two calls to `onChildAdded`? I've never seen it call `onChildAdded` more than once for a single child with a single listener. Are you sure you're really registering the `ChildEventListener` only once.

Comment: I am using this inside a background service. That's may be a problem. But I am not getting it.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show any reason why `onChildAdded` would be called multiple times. This is also not an area where the Firebase Realtime Database SDK is known to have problems, or has recently been changed. Unfortunately it's hard for me to say what's going beyond that based on what you shared. I recommend trying to reproduce the problem from scratch in a mini-project, and see when it starts happening.